# Dynamic Query with JPQL

Tags: sql, spring-boot, jpql

I'm trying to do a dynamic query whos receive an parameter and an input

```
@Query("SELECT i FROM Imovel i WHERE CONCAT_WS('.','i', :paramFiltro)  LIKE %:input%")
List<Imovel> findWithParamFiltro(@Param("input") String input, @Param("paramFiltro") String paramFiltro);
```

it's returning [[ ]]. If I change the CONCAT to i.endereco for example, I'll works fine.

There's a way to do this?

Comment: you can't repöace table por column names like that, you need use normal string concatination